# Merging computed file contents and display previous computed data in output

Tags: python, pandas

I am working to 2 files, **oldFile.txt** and **newFile.txt** and compute some changes between them. The **newFile.txt** is updated constantly and any updates will be written to **oldFile.txt**

I am trying to improve the snippet below by saving previous computed values and add it to a **finalOutput.txt**. Any idea will be very helpful to accomplish the needed output. Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
def read_file(fn):
    data = {}
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        for lines in f:
            line = lines.rstrip()
            pname, cnt, cat = line.split(maxsplit=2)
            data.update({pname: {'pname': pname, 'cnt': int(cnt), 'cat': cat}})
    return data

def process_data(oldfn, newfn):  
    old = read_file(oldfn)
    new = read_file(newfn)

    u_data = {}
    for ko, vo in old.items():
        if ko in new:
            n = new[ko]
            
            old_cnt = vo['cnt']
            new_cnt = n['cnt']
            u_cnt = old_cnt + new_cnt
            tmp_old_cnt = 1 if old_cnt == 0 else old_cnt
            cnt_change = 100 * (new_cnt - tmp_old_cnt) / tmp_old_cnt
            u_data.update({ko: {'pname': n['pname'], 'cnt': new_cnt, 'cat': n['cat'],
                                'curr_change%': round(cnt_change, 0)}})
    for kn, vn in new.items():
        if kn not in old:        
            old_cnt = 1
            new_cnt = vn['cnt']
            cnt_change = 0
            vn.update({'cnt_change': round(cnt_change, 0)})        
            u_data.update({kn: vn})

    pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.0f}".format
    mydata = []
    
    for _, v in u_data.items():
        mydata.append(v)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
    df = df.sort_values(by=['cnt'], ascending=False)
    
    # Save to text file.
    with open('finalOutput.txt', 'w') as w:
        w.write(df.to_string(header=None, index=False))
        
    # Overwrite oldFile.txt
    with open('oldFile.txt', 'w') as w:
        w.write(df.to_string(header=None, index=False))

    # Print in console.
    df.insert(0, '#', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    print(df.to_string(index=False,header=True))
    
while True:
    oldfn = './oldFile.txt'
    newfn = './newFile.txt'
    process_data(oldfn, newfn)
    sleep(60)
```

oldFile.txt

```
e6c76e4810a464bc 1                   Hello(HLL)
65b66cc4e81ac81d 2           CryptoCars (CCAR)
c42d0c924df124ce 3            GoldNugget (NGT)
ee70ad06df3d2657 4             BabySwap (BABY)
e5b7ebc589ea9ed8 8            Heroes&E... (HE)
7e7e9d75f5da2377 3                Robox (RBOX)
```

newfile.txt   #-- content during 1st reading

```
e6c76e4810a464bc 34                  Hello(HLL)
65b66cc4e81ac81d 43           CryptoCars (CCAR)
c42d0c924df124ce 95            GoldNugget (NGT)
ee70ad06df3d2657 15             BabySwap (BABY)
e5b7ebc589ea9ed8 37            Heroes&E... (HE)
7e7e9d75f5da2377 23                Robox (RBOX)
755507d18913a944 49             CharliesFactory
```

newfile.txt    #-- content during 2nd reading

```
924dfc924df1242d 35              AeroDie (ADie)
e6c76e4810a464bc 34                  Hello(HLL)
65b66cc4e81ac81d 73           CryptoCars (CCAR)
c42d0c924df124ce 15            GoldNugget (NGT)
ee70ad06df3d2657 5              BabySwap (BABY)
e5b7ebc589ea9ed8 12            Heroes&E... (HE)
7e7e9d75f5da2377 19                Robox (RBOX)
755507d18913a944 169            CharliesFactory
```

newfile.txt    # content during 3rd reading

```
924dfc924df1242d 45             AeroDie (ADie)
e6c76e4810a464bc 2                  Hello(HLL)
65b66cc4e81ac81d 4           CryptoCars (CCAR)
c42d0c924df124ce 7            GoldNugget (NGT)
ee70ad06df3d2657 5             BabySwap (BABY)
e5b7ebc589ea9ed8 3            Heroes&E... (HE)
7e7e9d75f5da2377 6                Robox (RBOX)
755507d18913a944 9             CharliesFactory
```

oldFile.txt #-- Current output that needs improvement

```
#            pname  cnt               cat   curr_change%
 1 924dfc924df1242d   35    AeroDie (ADie)            29 
 2 755507d18913a944    9   CharliesFactory           -95
 3 c42d0c924df124ce    7  GoldNugget (NGT)           -53
 4 7e7e9d75f5da2377    6      Robox (RBOX)           -68
 5 ee70ad06df3d2657    5   BabySwap (BABY)             0
 6 65b66cc4e81ac81d    4 CryptoCars (CCAR)           -95
 7 e5b7ebc589ea9ed8    3  Heroes&E... (HE)           -75
 8 e6c76e4810a464bc    2        Hello(HLL)           -94
```

finalOutput.txt #-- Needed Improved Output with additional columns r1, r2 and so on depending on how many update readings

```
# curr_change% is the latest 3rd reading
# r2% is based on the 2nd reading
# r1% is based on the 1st reading

 #            pname  cnt               cat  curr_change%    r2%      r1%
 1 924dfc924df1242d   35    AeroDie (ADie)            29      0        0
 2 755507d18913a944    9   CharliesFactory           -95    245        0
 3 c42d0c924df124ce    7  GoldNugget (NGT)           -53    -84    3,067
 4 7e7e9d75f5da2377    6      Robox (RBOX)           -68    -17      667
 5 ee70ad06df3d2657    5   BabySwap (BABY)             0    -67      275
 6 65b66cc4e81ac81d    4 CryptoCars (CCAR)           -95     70    2,050
 7 e5b7ebc589ea9ed8    3  Heroes&E... (HE)           -75    -68      362
 8 e6c76e4810a464bc    2        Hello(HLL)           -94      0    3,300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated for feedback, I made adjustments so that it would handle data that was fed to it live.  Whenever new data is loaded, load the file name into process_new_file() function, and it will update the 'finalOutput.txt'.

For simplicity, I named the different files file1, file2, file3, and file4.

I'm doing most of the operations using the pandas Dataframe.  I think working with Pandas DataFrames will make the task a lot easier for you.

Overall, I created one function to read the file and return a properly formatted DataFrame.  I created a second function that compares the old and the new file and does the calculation you were looking for.  I merge together the results of these calculations.  Finally, I merge all of these calculations with the last file's data to get the output you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

global global_old_df
global results_df
global count

global_old_df = None
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0


def read_file(file_name):

    rows = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
      for line in f:
         rows.append(line.split(" ", 2))
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['pname', 'cnt', 'cat'])
    df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.strip()
    df['cnt'] = df['cnt'].astype(float)

    return df


def compare_dfs(df_old, df_new, count):

    df_ = df_old.merge(df_new, on=['pname', 'cat'], how='outer')
    df_['r%s' % count] = (df_['cnt_y'] / df_['cnt_x'] - 1) * 100
    df_ = df_[['pname', 'r%s' % count]]
    df_ = df_.set_index('pname')

    return df_


def process_new_file(file):

    global global_old_df
    global results_df
    global count

    df_new = read_file(file)

    if global_old_df is None:
        global_old_df = df_new
        return

    else:
        count += 1
        r_df = compare_dfs(global_old_df, df_new, count)
        results_df = pd.concat([r_df, results_df], axis=1)
        global_old_df = df_new

        output_df = df_new.merge(results_df, left_on='pname', right_index=True)
        output_df.to_csv('finalOutput.txt')
        pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.1f}".format
        print(output_df.to_string())




files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']

for file in files:
    process_new_file(file)
```

This gives the output:

```
              pname  cnt                cat    r3    r2      r1
0  924dfc924df1242d 45.0     AeroDie (ADie)  28.6   NaN     NaN
1  e6c76e4810a464bc  2.0         Hello(HLL) -94.1   0.0 3,300.0
2  65b66cc4e81ac81d  4.0  CryptoCars (CCAR) -94.5  69.8 2,050.0
3  c42d0c924df124ce  7.0   GoldNugget (NGT) -53.3 -84.2 3,066.7
4  ee70ad06df3d2657  5.0    BabySwap (BABY)   0.0 -66.7   275.0
5  e5b7ebc589ea9ed8  3.0   Heroes&E... (HE) -75.0 -67.6   362.5
6  7e7e9d75f5da2377  6.0       Robox (RBOX) -68.4 -17.4   666.7
7  755507d18913a944  9.0    CharliesFactory -94.7 244.9     NaN
```

So, to run it live, you'd just replace that last section with:

```
while True:
    newfn = './newFile.txt'
    process_new_file(newfn)
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: Your idea is very helpful. I am trying to work on it and grasp how to implement this. In my case, the newFile.txt content is changing every few minutes. In your approach, its presume that all the contents are there before producing the finalOutput.txt

Comment: I edited the answer.  I think that addresses your issue.  Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Its working now. One more clarification. How can I display to the console the contents of finalOutput.txt in the format (#, pname, cnt, cat, r3, r2, r1)? The r3 is being the latest update and the r1 being the first. I also need to limit the percentage to 1 decimal point (-93.2, 10.0, 9.3). For reference, check my finalOutput.txt #-- Needed Improved Output

Comment: To reverse the order of r1, r2, r3, just reverse the order of the concat:          results_df = pd.concat([r_df, results_df], axis=1)  Then to print only 1 decimal, change the print display options and print the dataframe.        pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.1f}".format
        print(output_df.to_string())  Edits made to answer.

Comment: Its all good. Thank you. So much to understand to move forward.